# HeapAlloc bookkeeping

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, heap-memory

I've read (http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html), that HeapAlloc allocates some memory for bookkeeping in addition to the memory block requested. The size of bookkeeping info should be 40 bytes (8 bytes before the block and 32 after).

However, when I run a test with my VS2010, the actual memory consumed turns out to be significantly less.
For example, I insert 1M ints into a set. I wrote a hook function for malloc to make sure that every insertion triggers a separate dynamic memory allocation request to construct a new node. One node, according to hook, takes 20 bytes. If we add 80 bytes overhead, the total memory for one node should be 100 bytes. That is the set should consume ~ 100 megs, while according to TaskManager it takes as little as 32 megs.

Therefore, I have following questions:

Is the overhead really 40 bytes?
Does the overhead apply to every HeapAlloc'ed block?

Comment: You'll use the Low Fragmentation Heap for these small allocations on recent Windows versions, it has much less overhead per allocation.  Granularity is 8 bytes so you'd use 24 bytes for a node.  No idea what the extra two pointers might be, you can google this as well as I can.

Comment: Hans Passant, I think you are right. Seems that LFH uses 8 byte headers for blocks and it is the only overhead. I tested also by allocating 1M ints with new() and it took 16 megs - 8 by granularity and 8 by headers. Probably, it would be better if you post this comment as an answer.

Comment: It isn't an answer until somebody figures out what that overhead looks like.  I don't care quite enough to dig this out, it isn't that interesting.  Sorry.  You can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The overhead of a heap allocation changes from one version of Windows to the next, and it even changes within a single version, depending on various settings. (LFH, FTH, GFlags, IsDebuggerPresent) What is the practical programming problem you're having where you think understanding HeapAlloc bookkeeping is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a matter of confusion. I'm not sure if task manager shows physical or virtual memory.

If your allocations are going to swap file they might not be reflected in Task Manager. You should try more advanced performance monitoring tools.

Comment: Well, Task Manager shows working set and commit size. Working set should be more or less equal to the amount of physical memory consumed by the process.

Comment: Try to use at least this tool: http://www.warecase.com/products.asp it can show you much more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure `malloc` doesn't call HeapAlloc for every allocation, I would expect. Certainly in the case of glibc, the OS is only called to give a larger chunk of memory, and that is split - with a smaller overhead than the OS allocation overhead.

You could test that by taking the time of calling `malloc` vs calling `HeapAlloc` one million times for a small block of memory (e.g. 20 bytes). Which takes longer? If HeapAlloc is faster, then it's plausible that `HeapAlloc` is called for every `malloc` - but I expect that `malloc` is significantly faster.

Comment: Hm, I actually looked into debug malloc implementation and it really calls HeapAlloc each time. Probably, release version is more optimized, but I have about the same difference in sizes even for debug build (taking into cosideration, that debug CRT allocates more memory to write no_mans_land and block headers).

Comment: At least since Visual C++ 2010, `malloc` will call `HeapAlloc` for every allocation.